# Is a python script to upload a file to website with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, sendkeys

i m tring to upload a file to this web 'https://convertir-pdf.com/' doing webscraping whit a python notebok for a clase work but i cannot find the correct part of the html to do upload or click the button. My code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os

chrome_path = "D:\Descargas\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get('https://avi-a-mp4.convertir-pdf.com/')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.switch_to_frame(0)
driver.find_element_by_id("download").send_keys(mypath+ '\\' + onlyfiles[7])
#driver.find_element_by_id('single-upload-form').send_keys(mypath+ '\\' + onlyfiles[7])
#driver.find_element_by_id('single-upload-form').click()
```

and the error i have all the time is this:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="download"]"}


(Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.92)
```

Comment: First thing is the element you are using is `<a>` it should be `<input>` with `type=file`. which is not present. you should use some other 3rd party lib to simulate this type of file uploading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below xpath to resolve your issue

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@id='resumable-browse']"))).click()
```

**Note :** please add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Updated solution :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver  = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\New folder\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://avi-a-mp4.convertir-pdf.com/")
driver.maximize_window()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@id='resumable-browse']"))).click()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Do you think this is gonna work with `send_keys()` ?

Comment: I think you need au3 script

Comment: with this code the script do this exception: 'TimeoutException: Message: '

I'm very new with the scraping and I'm a little bit lost